# Dlib 19.4 will not build with cmake on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiling, c++

This is the error I get while building:

```
cmake --build . --config Release
[ 23%] Built target dlib
[ 23%] Linking CXX executable sqlite_ex
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) [clone .isra.60]':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `table_exists(dlib::database&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x137): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x171): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x3bc): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x4d4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x51e): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x5c1): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x6fc): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o:sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text+0x73c): more undefined references to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)' follow
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `dlib::randm(long, long)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib5randmEll[_ZN4dlib5randmEll]+0xd3): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_PKS5_[_ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_PKS5_]+0xa1): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_PKS5_[_ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_PKS5_]+0xd1): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EEPKS5_OS8_[_ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EEPKS5_OS8_]+0x23): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf()':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED2Ev[_ZNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED5Ev]+0x7): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf()':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED0Ev[_ZNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED5Ev]+0x7): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `dlib::statement::statement(dlib::database&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statementC2ERNS_8databaseENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN4dlib9statementC5ERNS_8databaseENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0xfc): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `dlib::database::exec(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x1ef): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x2fd): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x344): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x3e9): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o:sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN4dlib8database4execERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x52c): more undefined references to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)' follow
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>::operator=(dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout> const&)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEaSERKS4_[_ZN4dlib6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEaSERKS4_]+0x17a): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `std::ostream& dlib::operator<< <dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout> >(std::ostream&, dlib::matrix_exp<dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout> > const&)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x4d): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x9e): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0xde): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0xea): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x15f): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x3b0): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x3de): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_sync(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x56b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x58d): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x5c9): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x5eb): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x672): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x719): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x725): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x731): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x768): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x76f): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x7ef): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x813): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE[_ZN4dliblsINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEERSoS6_RKNS_10matrix_expIT_EE]+0x81a): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `void dlib::statement::bind_object<dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout> >(unsigned long, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout> const&)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0x4a): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0x5c): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0xd2): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0xde): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0x14f): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0x307): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0x313): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:
....
(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0x57a): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0x750): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_[_ZN4dlib9statement11bind_objectINS_6matrixIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEEEvmRKT_]+0x77b): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `void dlib::deserialize<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>(dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, std::istream&)':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib11deserializeIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEvRNS_6matrixIT_XT0_EXT1_ET2_T3_EERSi[_ZN4dlib11deserializeIdLl0ELl0ENS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEENS_16row_major_layoutEEEvRNS_6matrixIT_XT0_EXT1_ET2_T3_EERSi]+0xa10): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `main':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x83): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2af): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x401): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x648): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x829): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8fa): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x90c): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x999): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9a5): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa1e): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa9e): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_sync(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xaf0): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xafc): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb08): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb33): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd90): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xddc): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe28): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf21): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf5d): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o:sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xfba): more undefined references to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)' follow
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/sqlite_ex.cpp.o: In function `main':
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x117f): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x122f): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1372): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15b4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x171c): undefined reference to `VTT for std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1994): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1ac3): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1b1b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1c40): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)'
sqlite_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2299): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_istringstream()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/build.make:104: recipe for target 'sqlite_ex' failed
make[2]: *** [sqlite_ex] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sqlite_ex.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I was googling errors and the closest I got was that c and c++ compilers were ones that were creating this mess, I have both version 5.4.1. I tries to downgrade to 4.8 but then cmake would not recognize c++ compiler. I've spend a few days trying to fix this but am out of ideas.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: You might want to strip down your error output and put most of it to e.g. http://paste.ubuntu.com and link it in your question. That would make your question easier to read and more clear.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error on my 16.04 system with gcc/g++ 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04 - at least, it got well past the `sqlite_ex` part (I killed it at 63% because it had been compiling for 12+ hrs at that point - this was on a pretty resource-limited VM). My best *guess*, based on this [so] discussion [linker can not find symbols but they're there?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41152005/4440445) is that at least one of your `.o` files was compiled with an older version of GCC

Comment: @steeldriver supposing some of the files related to sqlite (where my problem lies), have to be recompiled. How would one go about just recompiling **that** specific part? (Sorry, I just started with linux)